3D animated movie, space story with alien princess
I can’t find this movie anywhere on the internet maybe I’m not looking hard enough or something.
It’s a 3D animated space story aimed at kids about a boy that was frustrated with something (I couldn’t remember) and an alien princess who wants to have friends so she disguises herself as a regular human.
I can’t remember a few parts but they became friends but then at a party someone’s grandma talks about her parents and stuff so the girl gets angry and reveals herself as the princess.
A few scenes later the boy becomes friends with her again, and this time she’s accepted by the community. The end.
This was pretty much all that I can remember but the part where the girl reveals herself as the princess was the most prominent thing I remembered.

In roughly which year did you watch this?
